# Load operation failed for query 'Login'. Base 64 string error

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-membership

I had an error Load operation failed for query 'Login'. With details connected with Base 64 string error. It was on a fresh db, with single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such an error on WebContext.Current.Authentication.Login(...), check if aspnet_Membership row for the user with error has proper values. In my case problem was PasswordSalt which was generated from MSSQL NEWID() - it wasn't proper PasswordSalt value.

Hope it can help someone :)